# Как отрисовать анимация Activity , без перехода на новую Activity . Эффект нужен для скриншота

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать чтобы по нажатию на кнопку  появилось как будто из  середины ( Ну или использовать другую анимацию  эффект) нужен для скриншота.

Comment: С фрагментами и с кастомной view такое можно сделать, но вопрос слишком общий чтоб дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: а как вы делаете скриншот?